# Contraction of Einstein field equation

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, curvature

In the paper "Physical and Geometric Interpretations of the Riemann Tensor, Ricci Tensor, and Scalar Curvature" by Lee C. Loveridge we can find the following paragraph:

> First we begin with Einstein’s equation written in terms of the Ricci
> tensor and scalar curvature
> $$ R_{μν} − \frac{1}{2} Rg_{μν} = 8πGT_{μν} $$
> and contract both sides to get
> $$ R = −8πGT $$.

I do not known the meaning of "contract" in this context. If contract means the trace:

$$ R_{νν} − \frac{1}{2} Rg_{νν} = R^v_νg_{νν} − \frac{1}{2} Rg_{νν} = Rg_{νν} − \frac{1}{2} Rg_{νν} = \frac{1}{2} Rg_{νν} $$

and:

$$ 8πGT_{νν} = 8πGT^ν_{ν}g_{νν} = 8πGTg_{νν} $$

that results in:

$$ \frac{1}{2} R = 8πGT $$

with a -1/2 difference respect to the expected result.

Comment: $R_{\nu\nu}$ is not a contraction and it isn’t a scalar. You have to contract an upper index with a lower index to get another tensor of smaller-by-2 rank.

Comment: @G.Smith: thanks for your comment. About "it isn't a scalar", note steps $R_{\nu\nu}=R^\nu_\nu g_{\nu\nu}=Rg_{\nu\nu}$.

Comment: Sorry, but that equation does not make sense. You cannot have two lower indices which are the same. And you can’t have *four* indices that are the same!

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to learn GR without first properly understanding SR in tensor notation. I suggest going back to Lorentz transformations, looking at how an arbitrary tensor $C_{\mu\nu}$ transforms, and convincing yourself that ${C^\mu}_\mu$ is Lorentz-invariant but $C_{\mu\mu}$ is *not*. You can perversely define $C_{\mu\mu}$ as $\sum_\mu C_{\mu\mu}$ but it has *no physical significance* because it is not a tensor of *any* rank; it does not transform like a tensor should.

Comment: @G.Smith: no one learns to add until they try to multiply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In General Relativity, contraction of two indices is done using the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. In this case, you would hit both sides of the equality with the metric tensor noting that $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu} = D$, where $D$ is the dimension of spacetime, in this case $D=4$.

Thus:

$$g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu} -\frac12R g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = R -\frac{D}{2}R = 8\pi G g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi G T$$